# Cross-compiling ncurses 5.9 for ARM - form lib not found

Tags: c++, linux, ncurses

I'm trying to cross-compile ncurses 5.9 for ARM for the purpose of porting GNU nano editor to this architecture. I've built my toolchain using crosstool-ng and the build finished without any problems. When trying to make GNU nano I've received some error messages concerning missing ncurses libs in my toolchain, what indeed is true. I've downloaded ncurses 5.9 and configured is as follows:

`./configure arm-linux --target=arm-linux --with-shared --prefix=/opt/x-tools/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi`

Then I've tried to make ncurses 5.9 with following command:

`make HOSTCC=gcc CXX=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-c++`

And this part resulted in error:

`/opt/x-tools/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/4.3.2/../../../../arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lform
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

From the error I assume I'm missing a library or a header "form.h" or "form.o". Could you point me to package containing this missing lib?

Host OS is Debian 7.6 i386.

Answer (score 0):

I just found an answer [here](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=printview&t=43766&start=0). You just need to add to the configuration script **--without-cxx-binding** switch. Also you can refer to [this](http://www.drobospace.com/forums/showthread.php?tid=1679) link, where you'll find detailed ncurses 5.9 cross-compile instructions.